# To separate STRING and INTEGER in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a column which contains both string and integer( Eg: 125D , S234,.. ) 
Now I want to separate the integer and the string. How to do this in  SQL server???

Comment: is this a one time operation, or will you need to repeat this as a data cleansing operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you need.  If it's more than a one time thing, you could make this into a function.  Or maybe you could split it a load time, if you have some sort of ETL process.

```
DECLARE @MyString varchar(1000) = 'A1b2C3';

declare @Counter integer = 1;
declare @currChar char(1) = '';;
declare @charString varchar(1000) = '';
declare @intString varchar(1000) = '';



while (@Counter <= len(@MyString))
begin
 set @currChar = substring(@MyString,@Counter,1)
   if isNumeric(@currChar) = 1
          set @intString = @intString + @currChar
   else
       set @charString = @charString + @currChar

  set @counter = @counter + 1
end

select @charString;
select cast(@intString as integer)
```